# Laravel add class using if statement

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to use Bootstrap carousel and the images should come from my database

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach($property->photos as $photo)
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{$photo->path}}" alt="First slide">
            </div>
        @endforeach 
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the page I can see that the image is there, however I will not see anything of it because I need the class active in the div with class carousel-item.

Is there a way I can add the class active on the first box?

I tried using jQuery but it does not work:

```
$('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first-child').addClass('active');
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Am using version 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first-child').addClass('active');
}
```

or not?
because for run jq code you need wait for document to ready!

Comment: I use yes, but now that you made double check I just noticed that I was placing the code inside a wrong function. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 4):

You can use [The loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable) to accomplish this:

```
@foreach($property->photos as $photo)
    <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{$photo->path}}" alt="First slide">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That helps too. Appreciate the support